# Push Notification in android with firebase get token

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

I want to do push notification and this my code

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        Log.e("NEW_TOKEN", s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("FCM NOTIFICATION");
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon((R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

but it's not work and I think this problem with a token I have seen a lot of questions and answers about get token but I couldn't get useful info there. I would be grateful any answer, Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( MainActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
            String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
            Log.e("newToken",newToken);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: follow this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Have you initialized FirebaseMessaging in Activity?

Comment: Do you have registered the service in the manifest? Because sometimes people forget to include in the manifest. Please check it again.

Comment: Meet Patel yes I did it

Comment: check firebase connection

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you not receiving the notification when the app is in foreground or when it is in background or both cases don't work? Or are you concerned with getting a new token? Please explain your problem precisely.

Comment: Do you implement the FCMInstanceIdService too?

Comment: Both cases it doesn't work

Comment: on the top all my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way.
1. Create a Service

```
public class YourService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

public static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "2")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_icon)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (NOTIFICATION_ID > 1073741824) {
        NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
    }
    Objects.requireNonNull(notificationManager).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, mNotifyBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Now add this to Manifest

```
<service
   android:name=".YourService"
   android:exported="false">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```