# Firebase Foreground Notifications Not Showing

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-notifications

For some reason my Firebase notifications are not showing in the foreground. They work fine in the background however, and I followed what Anroid Studio told me to add as well as this [tutorial example on github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/java/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java)

Judging by the Run window, it is receiving the notification but not sending in foreground

Here is my service code for sending the notification

```
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import static android.support.constraint.Constraints.TAG;

public class FirebaseNotificationsRecieverService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = FirebaseNotificationsRecieverService.class.getName();

    public FirebaseNotificationsRecieverService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // ...
        System.out.println("RECIEVED");
        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // Not getting messages here? See why this may be: (there was a link here)
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
                //scheduleJob();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                handleNow();
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
    private void handleNow() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.wlmaclogo)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.fcm_message))
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.starenkysoftware.macapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <service
            android:name=".FirebaseNotificationsRecieverService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
        <service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: have you defined the service in the manifest?

Comment: Yup. Just added the manifest^ if you could check it out to make sure it's fine. My run module says "Connected to remote service" and then "Inactivity, disconnecting from service" but when I push a notification it seems to start it again.

Comment: I added a System.out.println("RECIEVED"); to see if it even calls the onMessageReceived but it didn't print anything so I don't think its calling the method

Comment: Try it like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609283/push-notification-in-android-with-firebase-get-token/52611381#52611381

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the manifest as below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.starenkysoftware.macapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

    <service android:name=".FirebaseNotificationsRecieverService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The intent filter `com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT` should be placed in your service, which you are using to get the notifications.

Comment: Thank you so much this fixed everything! Could you please tell me how to switch out the `.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.fcm_message))` for the title that comes with the firebase notification? I tried passing the remoteMessage to the `sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` and it worked for description, but  `remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle()`  for title gives error `Cannot resolve method 'getString(java.lang.String)'`

Answer (score 0):

Remember to remove the existing messaging service from the AndroidManifest.xml.  If you leave the FireBaseMessagingService in the Manifest.  your newly defined service doesn't get picked up.

E.g. remove the following:

```
    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

and add the following:

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseNotificationService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```